# Analytic continuation of a function of real variable.

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem comes from Basic Complex Analysis by Marsden and Hoffman.

Let $h(x)$ be a function of real variable $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that 
$$h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,$$
which converges for $x$ in some interval $(-\eta,\eta)$ around $0$, where $\eta>0$. Prove that $h$ is the restriction of some analytic function defined in a neighborhood of $0$.

I've tried lots of things but can't get a solid proof. I've attempted to use Schwarz Reflection Principle but couldn't get anywhere with it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it's the fundamental lemma of power series : $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges on $]-R,R[$ iff $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| |x|^n$ converges on $]-R,R[$ i.e. iff $a_n = \mathcal{O}(R^{-n})$ (hence all the derivatives  of $f(x)$ converge too)

Comment: there exists a constant $C$ such that for every $n$ : $|a_n| < \frac{C}{R^n}$

Comment: you should look at a course on the convergence of power series, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence

Comment: Use the fact that if a series converges then the $a_n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: If your function is represented as: $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot x^n$, then what can you say about the function represented as: $h(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot z^n$, for $z$ on the upper half plane, with $0\le |z|\lt \eta$?After that, consider the Schwarz Reflection Principle.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis : I don't think it is related to the Schwarz reflection principle. simply say that if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for $x \in ]-\eta,\eta[$ then $a_n = o(\eta^{-n})$ hence $f(z)$ converges absolutely for $|z| < \eta$

Comment: @user1952009: I'm don't commonly use little o notation. What does $o(\eta^{-n})$ mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation you should use those, for example the 1st order Taylor approximation is $f(x+h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + o(h)$

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis It will be convergent, and so analytic on that set.

Comment: The *series* $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot z^n$ will be convergent. Now what can you say about the *function* this series represents based on Taylor's Theorem of uniqueness?

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis I got you!!!!! Thanks!!

Comment: Good. Now extend your result to the lower half plane for $0\le |z|\lt\eta$ by the Reflection Principle and you are done.

Comment: Schwarz reflection is irrelevant. If a power series converges absolutely or conditionally for some real or complex $z_0 \ne 0$, then it converges absolutely for all complex $z$ for which $|z| < |z_0|$. When applied to your case, the power series converges absolutely in $|z| < \eta$. The resulting function of $z$ in $|z| < \eta$ is holomorphic, and the restriction of that holomorphic function to the real axis is the given function.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis Quick question. Why must I break it down into these two situations? I ask this because I first assumed that $h$ could be analytically continued to the open disk $D(0,\eta)$

Comment: You don't have to. You mentioned the Reflection Principle, that's why I led you there. You can just use the holomorphic nature of the resultant function like TrialAndError says.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis ah I see. Thanks man! I really appreciate it. May I share the proof I wrote with you?

Comment: Why don't you write it as an answer to your own question? It's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges for all $x\in(-\eta,\eta)$. Then, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n|z|^n<\infty,$$
where $|z|<\eta$. Thus, 
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$
is convergent for all $z$ contained in the open neighborhood $D(0,\eta)=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid |z|<\eta\right\}$. Therefore, $h=f\vert_{(-\eta,\eta)}$ as it was to be demonstrated.